# str_replace not working in for each

Tags: php, str-replace

i want to use str_replace in `foreach` but it's not working

```
<?php
$html = '<p><span style="color: #0099cc;">This is Some Text</span><span style="color: #0099cc;"><br /><br />This is Some Text<br /></span><br /><span style="color: #009999;">This is Some Text<br /><br /></span>This is Some Text<br /><br /><span style="color: #336699;">This is Some Text</span><br /><span style="color: #ff0066;">This is Some Text<br /><br />This is Some Text<br /></span><br /><span style="color: #ff0066;">This is Some Text</span><br />This is Some Text<br /><br /><img src="http://shop.about.com/pic/android2014-1.jpg" alt="" /></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="color: #ff0000;">Price 11111</span></strong></p>
<p><a href="addcart.php?action=add&amp;id=373" target="_blank"><img src="http://shop.about.com/pic/buy2.gif" alt="" border="0" /></a><br /><br /></p>
<div align="justify">This is Some Text<br />This is Some Text<br /><br />This is Some Text<br />This is Some TextThis is Some Text<br /><br />
<div align="center"><img src="http://shop.about.com/pic/android2014-2.jpg" alt="" /><br />
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="color: #ff0000;">This is Some Text:</span>This is Some Text</strong></p>
<a href="addcart.php?action=add&amp;id=373" target="_blank"><img src="http://shop.about.com/pic/buy2.gif" alt="" border="0" /></a><br /><br />
<div align="justify">This is Some Text<br />This is Some Text<br />This is Some Text<br />This is Some Text<br />This is Some Text<br />This is Some Text<br /><br />
<div align="center"><img src="http://shop.about.com/pic/android2014-3.jpg" alt="" /><br /><br />
<div align="justify">This is Some Text<br /><br />
<div align="center"><strong><span style="color: #ff0000;">This is Some TextThis is Some Text</span>This is Some Text) This is Some Text</strong><br /><br /><a href="pic/android2014-7.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="http://shop.about.com/pic/android2014-6.jpg" alt="" align="bottom" border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" /></a> <a href="pic/android2014-5.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="http://shop.about.com/pic/android2014-4.jpg" alt="" /></a><br />
<div align="justify">
<div align="justify">
<p style="text-align: justify;"><span style="font-weight: normal;" lang="fa"><span style="color: #ff0000;">This is Some Text:</span>This is Some Text</span></p>
</div>
</div>
<br />
<p style="text-align: center;"><br /><strong><span style="color: #ff0000;">This is Some Text: </span>This is Some This is Some Text</strong></p>
<a href="addcart.php?action=add&amp;id=373" target="_blank"><img src="http://shop.about.com/pic/buy2.gif" alt="" border="0" /></a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>';



$random_name = array(
"http://shop.about.com/pic/android2014-1.jpg" => "127.0.01/857513428.jpg" ,
"http://shop.about.com/pic/buy2.gif" => "127.0.01/673828126.jpg" ,
"http://shop.about.com/pic/android2014-2.jpg" => "127.0.01/824005127.jpg" ,
"http://shop.about.com/pic/android2014-3.jpg" => "127.0.01/927673340.jpg" ,
"http://shop.about.com/pic/android2014-6.jpg" => "127.0.01/274383545.jpg" ,
"http://shop.about.com/pic/android2014-4.jpg" => "127.0.01/175170899.jpg"


);

foreach ( $random_name as $key => $value ) {
$test3 = str_replace($key , $value , $html);    

}


echo $test3;

?>
```

so here you can see

i have one variable with name `$html`
and one array with name `$random_name`

i want to replace all values in `$random_names` with them keys into `$html`

so i write `foreach' as`$key => $value`

but unfortunately it doesn't working

how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: No need to use foreach: just use `$newhtml = str_replace(array_keys($random_name), $random_name, $html);`

Comment: @MarkBaker for some reason i must to use 'foreach' why it's not working with foreach ?

Comment: This is a heinous abuse of array keys. Also, it might help to say how is it not working. Expected vs actual output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace directly, then instead of this:

```
$test3 = str_replace($key , $value , $html);
```

write this:

```
$html = str_replace($key , $value , $html);
```

and at the end, `echo $html`.

Or if you want to store it in a `$test3` variable, then something like this:

```
$test3 = $html;
foreach ( $random_name as $key => $value ) {
    $test3 = str_replace($key, $value, $test3);
}
echo $test3;
```

Comment: Thankyou , it work's fine , but can you explain me why it's not working in `$html` we just copying `$html` into `$test3` why we can't use it directly ?

Comment: You can use directly too, I have just offered you another way to do, if maybe you would need the original $html somewhere :) But if you don't need the real one, then it is better to use the direct way.

Comment: thanks a lot :) , i understand it better now , but why i can't use another variable name like `$test3 = str_replace($key , $value , $html);` what is problem of this ?

Comment: Because that way you are always overwriting `$test3` in each iteration, so as a result you will only have the last element of your array replaced. I hope it is clear, if not, maybe I can write you an example to demonstrate what's wrong in that algorithm.

Comment: Let's say it's our array: `$random_name = array("a" => "0", "b" => "1", "c" => "2")`. By using your algorithm, in the first iteration the content of `$test3` will be `$html`, with all `"a"` replaced to `"0"`, and `$html` won't be modified. So until here, it is working as we want. But here comes the second iteration, when you are replacing all `"b"` to `"1"` in `$html`, and you move the result in `$test3`. So now `"a"`s won't be replaced, since your algorithm is working with the **original `$html`**. And since `$html` will never change, there will always be only one element replaced in `$test3`

Answer (score 0):

You are always using the unchanged variable `$html` as the variable to do the change in, so only the last iteration of your `foreach` loop will be reflected in your final value of `$test3`.

Answer (score 0):

One line solution:

```
$replaced_urls = str_replace(array_keys($random_name), array_values($random_name), $html);
```